# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add this [emoji-picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker) to my project. I followed the instructions but I get this error, net::ERR_ABORTED, every time.
Inside my project, the folders look like this: [image]

Here is the HTML header

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/memory.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Emoji tags here is the problem I think-->
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

script just before the end of the body tag

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/config.js"></script>
 <script src="js/util.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.emojiarea.js"></script>
 <script src="js/emoji-picker.js"></script>
```